# Linking content type nodes with each other

Tags: 6, nodes

I have two content types that I want to link each other. I checked node references, but node references only allows me to link to others when creating a node of that content type. What If I wanted to link two nodes of content types that are already created?

Please let me know if it is possible in Drupal-6.

Thanks

Comment: Then you _edit_ the node and add the reference

Comment: what if i want to add multiple references ? Also what if a User who did not create it want to reference it ?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually "link" nodes at any time, you just have to *edit* the node to add the reference.

If you want to add multiple references, you have to specify this when you set up the node reference field in your content type.  In the configuration page of the node reference field, choose how many references you want to allow (1-10, or unlimited).

For a user to add a reference that did not create the node, make sure the correct permissions are set in admin/user/permissions for the given user role. (ie "edit any EXAMPLE content")

Comment: I am using drupal Commons. But I don't see where I can change the node references when I click on edit ?

Comment: Are you the admin user? Have the template files been modified? Unfortunately there's not much I can tell you with the info given.  The field *should* be visible on the edit page

Comment: Can I setup permission in such a way that users can only edit the reference field ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to if you have the Content Permissions sub-module of CCK enabled.  Go back to the permissions page and find the **content_permissions module** heading.  Then all of the fields will be listed and you can choose which fields each role can edit, etc